# ExceptionInInitializerError while trying to launch JNLP screen

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, classpath, jnlp

**Machine : Windows 64 Bit**

**Java Installed : Jre6, Jre7**

**Classpath contains : Jdk6, Jdk7**

Stack Trace :

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.jniwrapper.win32.ie.Browsers.getIEVersion(Unknown Source)
    at com.amdocs.uif.widgets.browser.JExplorerBrowserFactory.initialize(JExplorerBrowserFactory.java:254)
    at com.amdocs.uif.workspace.MDIWorkspace.initialize(MDIWorkspace.java:1351)
    at com.amdocs.uif.workspace.MDIWorkspace.<init>(MDIWorkspace.java:1305)
    at com.amdocs.uif.workspace.MDIWorkspace.<init>(MDIWorkspace.java:1284)
    at com.amdocs.uif.workspace.RuntimeContext.main(RuntimeContext.java:287)
    at com.amdocs.uif.workspace.Main.main(Main.java:24)
Caused by: com.jniwrapper.LibraryNotFoundException: Cannot find JNIWrapper native library (jniwrap64.dll) in java.library.path: C:\oms\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;%SONAR_RUNNER_HOME%\bin;C:\env\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;C:\env\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\bin;C:\env\jdk1.6.0_24\jre\bin\client;O:\ora11202w\bin;C:\ANT_HOME\bin;.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use 32 bit JVM . This should resolve the issue.